# Convert datagriview value to string

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've been trying so many ways, but nothing is working. It looks so simple and my head is about to explode. All I need is to make a label(Sales1) visible when my datagridview(`dgvLocation`) value <> nothing. here is what i have:

```
lblSales.Text = dgvLocation.Rows(0).Cells(1).value

If lblSales.Text <> nothing then 
    Sales1.Visible = true
End If
```

Comment: `If Not StringIsNullOrEmpty(lblSales.Text) Then...`

Comment: You could just set `lblSales.Visible = (dgvLocation.Rows(0).Cells(1).value IsNot Nothing)`

Comment: unbelievably, none of those methods worked either. wow,

Comment: Plutonix's method works if you fix the little typo. Did you try it as-is, or like "String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblSales.Text.ToString)"?

Comment: yeah.. :( i tried it like String.IsNullOrEmpty... including the Text.ToSrring and the label did not turn visible at all

Comment: There's no point testing the `Text` of a `Label` for `Nothing` because it can never be `Nothing`.  If a `Label` is blank the its `Text` is an empty `String`, not no `String` at all.  Testing for an empty `String` WILL work if your grid cell actually contains no value or an empty `String`.  If it doesn't work for you then obviously that's not what your grid cell contains.  There's no magic here. Do the obvious, i.e. test what your cell actually DOES contain.

Comment: I Knew it!!!!! .. omg! Plutonix method: lblSales.visible = (dgvLocation.Rows... works! but i needed to add "ToString" after value

Comment: What you **really** need is to turn on Option Strict so implicit conversions are not allowed

Answer (score 0):

The code should look like this:

```
Sales1.Visible = dgvLocation.Rows(0).Cells(1).value.ToString Is Not Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` method and check if the Value `Is Not Nothing`

```
If Not dgvLocation.Rows(0).Cells(1).value Is Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblSales.Text.Trim) Then

LblSales.Text = dgvLocation.Rows(0).Cells(1).value.Tostring

Sales1.Visible = True

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.ToString` throws `NullReferenceException` when the object is `Nothing`.
To convert reference type to String use `Convert.ToString(Object)` instead.

To check if value is not `Nothing`:

```
Sales1.Visible = dgvLocation(1, 0).Value IsNot Nothing
```

To check if value is not `Nothing`, `""`, or `DbNull.Value`:

```
Sales1.Visible = Convert.ToString(dgvLocation(1, 0).Value) > ""
```